# Blogger Featured Image Via Background Image Without Javascript

Tags: blogger

I'm making a Blogger theme and I'm trying to create a featured image for each post on the blogroll by grabbing the first image of each post and applying it as an element background image in each post. How can this be done?

So far I have gotten it to work somewhat, the problem is it applies the same image to every post, instead of each post. I tried putting it in a loop, but it didn't make a difference.

My code:

```
<b:loop values='data:post' var='this'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage'>
    <a class='featured-image-link' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
    <b:include data='{ image: data:post.featuredImage, selector: ".featured-image-link" }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
  <else/>
    <a class='featured-image-link' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
    <style>background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1AyCkdmJy98/Xa9kktaCsmI/AAAAAAAAfh0/zCRbtFo0di0iaU-eU5AWjx4Ndvt3sXmsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-light_1920x1080.png);</style>
  </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

EDIT:
Screenshot result, with or without the loop:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop won't work with this `values` and `var`, and you should write the selector before command for the alternative style, so you might try this one:

```html
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <a class='featured-image-link' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage'>
        <b:include data='{ image: data:post.featuredImage, selector: ".featured-image-link" }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
    <b:else/>
        <b:include data='{ image: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1AyCkdmJy98/Xa9kktaCsmI/AAAAAAAAfh0/zCRbtFo0di0iaU-eU5AWjx4Ndvt3sXmsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-light_1920x1080.png", selector: ".featured-image-link" }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
    </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

---

**Edit :**

I think you should use `id` attribute instead of `class` for your element, you can't use the same class for different generated styles, so depending on index of loop you can give each post a different id.

1- in the main loop of widget add attribute `index='i'`, it should be similar to:

```html
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post' index='i'>
```

2- Put this block of code within the main loop of widget:

```html
<a expr:id='("featured-image-link" + data:i)' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
<b:with value='data:post.featuredImage ?: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1AyCkdmJy98/Xa9kktaCsmI/AAAAAAAAfh0/zCRbtFo0di0iaU-eU5AWjx4Ndvt3sXmsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-light_1920x1080.png"' var='featuredImg'>
    <b:include data='{ image: data:featuredImg, selector: ("#featured-image-link" + data:i) }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
</b:with>
```

**Final code should be similar to:**

```html
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post' index='i'>
    <!-- your post elements -->
    <a expr:id='("featured-image-link" + data:i)' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
    <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage ?: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1AyCkdmJy98/Xa9kktaCsmI/AAAAAAAAfh0/zCRbtFo0di0iaU-eU5AWjx4Ndvt3sXmsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-light_1920x1080.png"' var='featuredImg'>
        <b:include data='{ image: data:featuredImg, selector: ("#featured-image-link" + data:i) }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
    </b:with>
    <!-- your post elements -->
</b:loop>
```

Comment: This didn't work. The result was every post had several copies of the same image, per post. So for example, if there are 10 posts on the homepage, and only one of them have a featured image, then all ten posts had ten copies of that featured image per post.

Comment: This code snippet only work properly if you remove the loop. Using the loop adds all images to every post. Without the loop, it works as desired. So if you edit this answer to not have the loop, I will accept it. Thank you for taking the time to try and answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `b:loop`, I think you are using it inside another one

```xml
  <a class='featured-image-link' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
  <b:if cond='data:post.featuredImage'>
    <b:include data='{ image: data:post.featuredImage, selector: ".featured-image-link" }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
  <b:else/>
    <b:include data='{ image: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1AyCkdmJy98/Xa9kktaCsmI/AAAAAAAAfh0/zCRbtFo0di0iaU-eU5AWjx4Ndvt3sXmsgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-light_1920x1080.png", selector: ".featured-image-link" }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
  </b:if>
```

Comment: I originally tried this and it showed the same image for every post, instead of just the post that had the image. See screenshot I added in question.

Comment: Hmm, did you try to use `data:post.firstImageUrl` instead of `data:post.featuredImage`?

Comment: I gave it a try, but `data:post.firstImageUrl` didn't work. I thought that was depreciated?